# Android System APIs

Tags: android, platform, sign

I use some APIs normally called by the system.
Therefore I add **android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"** to manifest.xml,
and sign my apk with Android's platform key (platform.pk8 & platform.x509.pem) from GIT.
Then my apk can be installed and works properly on emulator and some devices,
but it doesn't work on Galaxy Tab or other devices signed with different platform keys.

Can I sign certain file(s) on the system to make my apk work?
If yes, which one(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You must sign your APK with the platform key used on the specific build. If you don't have the Galaxy Tab's platform key, you're not going to be able to get it to work on that platform. Also, there is no single key that will work on all devices.

Might want to try and contact the vendor of the devices you want.